# What about 16Gb and 16GB for storage like flash drive?

Tags: storage

In case of data transmission or internet speed, 16Gb and 16GB both have different meanings.

What about 16Gigabits and 16Gigabytes for storage like flash drive? Does it make difference in case of storage or its same for storage?

Comment: bits and bytes are **always** different. No matter what capacity you are talking about a byte will always be a <machine word size> number of bits. For modern computers this has been synonymised with 8 bits. What differs is how much Giga, Mega and Kilo prefixes mean. Storage manufacturers use them as metric (base 10) prefixes, while "computer" people assume they are base-2 prefixes, i.e. 1024.

Comment: I've seen people (sellers) describing capacities of flash drives with "Gb" or even "gb", while they mean "GB". It's their mistake. I find it unprofessional and avoid such offers. I imagine I could buy 2GB drive in price of 16GB and the seller would say: 'What'ya mean? 16Gb *is* 2GB'. However I've never heard this happened to anybody.

Comment: It means, in case of storage like a pen drive, if we say, 16Gb (16gigabits), it’s incorrect.

Comment: Why is it incorrect? It's inconvenient but it's just as valid as 2GB... It's like saying it's wrong to state the price of petrol in gallons, but OK to state it in "3.78 liter".

Comment: @mtak If you say 2GB, you mean "_two billion **bytes**_"... this would be equivelant to 16Gb (aka "_sixteen billion **bits**_"). But that's not how things work - people list storage as "_2Gb_" or "_2gb_" when they actually mean "_2GB_"... it's incorrect and lazy.

Comment: I mean to say, if we say 16 gigabits instead of 16 gigabytes for a 16GB flash drive, is it same or can it be considered as correct?

Comment: It is _not_ the same, it is _not_ correct.

Answer (score 1):

- `b` means "*bits*" (little 'b')
- `B` means "*bytes*" (big 'B')

8 bits (typically) come together to form 1 byte.

They do have different meanings... always.

When discussing transmission rates, we typically use "*n **bits** per second*".
For example:

- xDSL / DOCSIS speed
- SATA speed
- Ethernet speed
- etc...

When discussing storage, we typically use "*b **bytes***".

- Hard disk size
- RAM size
- Flash storage size
- etc...

---

When discussing storage there is often a disconnect between what people mean - base-10 or base-2.

- When discussing file sizes, we typically see the "*TB*" style suffix, when in fact the "*TiB*" suffix would be more appropriate

  - 1TiB = 1024<sup>4</sup>
- When discussing hard disk sizes, we typically see the "*TB*" style suffix, which is correct

  - 1TB = 1000<sup>4</sup>

This leads to the confusion surrounding hard disk capacity.

A hard disk advertised as "*1TB*" has a capacity of ~1,000,000,000,000 bytes. This will resolve to ~931GiB, and then people get upset about the "*missing storage*". This is then exaserbated further as the filesystem will also take some of the available space, making the truly available "*usable*" space appear even smaller.

---

Having said that we typically use *bytes* when discussing RAM and flash storage - this is a fairly consumer-centric phenomenon that tends to apply to the finished product. If you inspect the datasheets for the actual components on the PCB, you will likely see the capacity listed in *bits*.